# After looping, which is the correct way of returning into a list all the iterated elements?

Tags: python, python-3.x, loops, data-structures

I have the following function which takes a `.html` document and extract some content:

```
        for e in soup.tbody.findAll('a', href=True):
            tree = etree.fromstring(str(e))
            for e in tree.xpath('//b'):
                # Here, instead of the above line, I would like to get in a single string all the printed elements in tree.xpath()
```

How can I return in list all the `e`s in `tree.xpath('//a')` in a single movement?. I tried to append into a new list each element and to                 `new_lis += element`, however it's not working.

Comment: Can you show examples of the desired output vs the current output?

Comment: I updated the question with the info, thanks @RobertValencia

Comment: So if you just use print, it prints all the iteration outputs, but if you append them to the list, it only saves the first iteration output?

Comment: That's correct @RobertValencia, what can I do order to get the desired output?.

Comment: Before the ```try``` statement, create a string ```s = ''```, then instead of printing, add each new element to ```s``` - ```s += 'www.example.com' + e.get('href')+' | title: ' + e.get('title')```.

Comment: @wwii, this one worked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two ways you can do this:

1. Simply push everything onto a list you create *outside of any of your loops (or use list comprehensions):

   ```
   def extract(html_file):
       soup = BeautifulSoup(open(html_file), 'lxml')
       results = []
       for e in soup.tbody.findAll('a', href=True):
           results.append(e['href'])

       return results

   def extract_with_list_comprehension(html_file):
       soup = BeautifulSoup(open(html_file), 'lxml')
       return [e['href'] for e in soup.tbody.findAll('a', href=True)]
   ```
2. Turn `extract` into a generator and just `yield` as you find things, and then iterate over the result:

   ```
   def extract(html_file):
       for e in BeautifulSoup(open(html_file), 'lxml').findAll('a', href=True):
           yield e['href']
   ```

   and then you can turn it into a list with `list` if you need to:

   ```
   all_links = list(extract('~/some/html/file.here'))
   ```

Comment: I tried with `extract_with_list_comprehension`. However it returned me `[None,
 None,
 None,
 None,
 None]`

Comment: Sorry, needed to use `['href']` to get the `href` attribute, rather than `.href` which gets a non-existent property on the element.

Answer (score 1):

Try building the desired string for each iteration, append the string to the list, then return the list:

```
def extract(html_file):
    url_list = []
    soup = BeautifulSoup(open(html_file), 'lxml')
    try:
        for e in soup.tbody.findAll('a', href=True):
            tree = etree.fromstring(str(e))
            for e in tree.xpath('//a'):
                url = 'www.example.com' + e.get('href')+' | title: ' + e.get('title'), '\n')
                url_list.append(url)
    except AttributeError:
        print('NaN')

    return url_list
```

Comment: @john doe does this get you the desired result?

Comment: No, this returned me the first element instead of the full iteration.